# VS2010 Beta 2 "Start new instance"

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

In VS2008, when I have a web service and a client of that web service in the same solution, I can debug the client by first selecting *Debug / Start new instance* on the web service project.  That launches the web service in the debugger and opens my default browser to show the root directory of the web service.  When I close the browser, VS2008 switches from the debugger back into development mode (leaving the web service running), and I'm able to begin debugging my client when I'm ready.

I just tried the same procedure (on a converted solution) with VS2010 Beta 2, and find that the debugger continues to run after closing the browser, leaving the option *Debug / Start Debugging* unavailable.

Is this a broken/missing feature?  Is there a different/better way to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, but I'm not sure. BTW: The VS2010 devs **urge** users who find bugs to report them asap, or they may not get into the release version. But to be honest I imagine someone has already reported this, but you could report it through MS connect, or the MSDN forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out pressing the STOP button in the debugger leaves the WCF service running.